# Set listener on WebView | nativescript + vue

Tags: android, vue.js, webview, nativescript

I am trying to play a video from YouTube and get the current-time by YT.API.

The video plays successfully and functions on HTML content works too,

But I can't figure it out how can I get data from this webView Element.

I want to be informed about events from webView,
this is my code:

```
<template>
<Page @loaded=pageLoaded>
    <GridLayout>
        <web-view id="webView"></web-view>
    </GridLayout>
</Page>
</template>
```

```
let webViewInterfaceModule = require('nativescript-webview-interface');

@Component 

export default class someComponent extends Vue {

    oWebViewInterface;

    pageLoaded(args){
        let page = args.object;
        this.setupWebViewInterface(page);
    }

    setupWebViewInterface(page){

        let webView = page.getViewById('webView');
        this.oWebViewInterface = new webViewInterfaceModule.WebViewInterface(webView, this.html);

        this.oWebViewInterface.on( '*', function(eventData){
            console.log("some change!!"); // but never fires!
        });

    }
}
```

and i define `this.html` as:

```
html = `
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
        <div id="player"></div>
        <script>

            var tag = document.createElement('script');

            tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
            var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

            var player;

            function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
                player = new YT.Player('player', {
                height: '280',
                width: '100%',
                videoId: 'k3On6DLPGLA',
                events: {
                    'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                }
                });
            }

            function onPlayerReady(event) {
                event.target.playVideo();
            }

            var done = false;
            function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
                console.log("state changed!"); // it fires!
            }

            function stopVideo() {
                player.stopVideo();
            }

    <\/script>
    <\/body>
    <\/html>
`;
```

but i just get such these results:

```
chromium: [ERROR:web_contents_delegate.cc(224)] WebContentsDelegate::CheckMediaAccessPermission: Not supported.
chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(35)] "state changed!", source: ..../ (35)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got the answer:

there is some issues here:

---

#1. implanting `nativescript-webview-interface.js`:

I need to copy this file:

`cp node_modules/nativescript-webview-interface/www/nativescript-webview-interface.js app/assets/www/lib/`

---

#2. permissions!

but #1 causes another problem: `net::ERR_ACCESS_DENIED`

for solving this one I add this:

```
setupWebViewInterface(page){
    let webView = page.getViewById('webView');
    webView.android.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
}
```

and now I have access to the folder so I moved `this.html` variable content to a new file : `/assets/www/index.html`

---

#3. setting src

since just now we have access to the folder, we need to (re)set the src of web-view so I add this one to the `setupWebViewInterface` Function:

`this.oWebViewInterface = new webViewInterfaceModule.WebViewInterface( webView, '~/assets/www/index.html' );`

note: I removed src from `<webView />` since it causes problem! (if old and new src would be the same it will not reload!)

---

#4.defining Variables:

in html file I need to add this line:

```
var oWebViewInterface = window.nsWebViewInterface;
```

---

#5. defining listener:

I add this one: `oWebViewInterface.emit('anyEvent', event);`
inside this function:

```
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    console.log("state changed!");
    oWebViewInterface.emit('anyEvent', event);
}
```

---

Now it works :)